Cohomology of Blow-ups and Minimal Models in Higher Dimensions
Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic zero. Consider a sequence of blow-ups:
$$X_n \xrightarrow{\pi_n} X_{n-1} \xrightarrow{\pi_{n-1}} \cdots \xrightarrow{\pi_2} X_1 \xrightarrow{\pi_1} X_0 = X$$
where each $\pi_i : X_i \to X_{i-1}$ is the blow-up of a smooth subvariety $Y_i \subset X_{i-1}$ of codimension at least 2.
Is there a general formula or method to compute the cohomology groups $H^i(X_n, \mathcal{O}_{X_n})$ in terms of the cohomology of $X$ and the blown-up subvarieties $Y_i$?
Suppose $X$ is of general type and $\dim X \geq 3$. Can we bound the number of blow-ups needed to reach a minimal model of $X$ in terms of its Hodge numbers or other invariants?
Let $\kappa(X)$ denote the Kodaira dimension of $X$. Is there a relationship between $\kappa(X_n)$ and $\kappa(X)$ that holds for all $n$, or can we at least bound $|\kappa(X_n) - \kappa(X)|$ in terms of $n$ and invariants of the $Y_i$?
In the context of the Minimal Model Program, how does this sequence of blow-ups interact with the Mori fiber space structure? More precisely, if $X$ admits a Mori fiber space structure $f: X \to Z$, can we describe conditions on the $Y_i$ that ensure $X_n$ also admits a Mori fiber space structure, possibly over a modification of $Z$?

Coherent cohomology doesn't change under smooth blowup, so
$$
H^i(X_n, \mathcal{O}_{X_n}) = H^i(X, \mathcal{O}_{X}).
$$
The Kodaira dimension also doesn't change. On the other hand, blowups don't get you closer to a minimal model, to go there you need to blow down...
